# How do I make an AJAX request to my file system in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, axios

I'm trying to unit test a script that will in part rely on data returned from an `axios.get()` request to an external resource.

One test function I have currently looks like this:

```
export function getFeedData (sub) {
    if (getFeedId(sub) === 2) {
        return axios.get('/src/mocks/MockData.json').then((data) => JSON.parse(data));
    }
}
```

This is failing, I believe, because `axios` will not make calls to the file system. Is there another library I can use that will allow me to make calls to the file system? Or a way I can get this to work with `axios`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design and a security feature.

What you could do is spin up a node server and have that act as a proxy between the client and the filesystem.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't actually know how to do that since I'm currently learning node but still a beginner. Are you able to point me toward a resource that would help me learn?

Comment: You can check out this page: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html 
That is node's api to the filesystem, so if you just start a node server, your front-end can make an ajax request to localhost:8080 (or whatever port you tell node to run on) and then you can have the node.js code interact with your filesystem however you like

Comment: @CJApel If I'm testing this script with Jest, would I start the server in the script that's being tested or in the same file as the tests themselves?

Comment: Since you mentioned that this is a unit test (as opposed to an integration test), I recommend that you mock the request. There are plenty of resources to learn about mocking ajax requests for unit testing -- that way, you can focus on the actual business logic as opposed to testing the network request itself